# Fluent syntax for IQueryable extension method?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I'll let the code speak for itself:

```
public interface ISoftDeletable {
  bool IsDeleted {get; set;}
}

public static class Extensions {
  public IQueryable<T> Active<T>(this IQueryable<T> q) where T : ISoftDeletable {
    return q.Where(t => !t.IsDeleted);
  }
}

public partial class Thing : ISoftDeletable {
  ...
}

...
var query = from tc in db.ThingContainers
            where tc.Things.Active().Any(t => t.SatisfiesOtherCondition)
            select new { ... }; // throws System.NotSupportedException
```

The error is:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.IQueryable`1[Thing] ActiveThing' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

You get the idea: I'd like a fluent kind of way of expressing this so that for any `ISoftDeletable` I can add on a 'where' clause with a simple, reusable piece of code.  The example here doesn't work because Linq2Entities doesn't know what to do with my `Active()` method.

The example I gave here is a simple one, but in my real code, the `Active()` extension contains a much more intricate set of conditions, and I don't want to be copying and pasting that all over my code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You haven't said *what* the exception is that you're getting, which makes it harder to help you. I'd expect what you've done so far to be fine - but more complicated examples wouldn't, e.g. using `Active` within a join.

Comment: @JonSkeet - added error message.  But yes, you're right, my actual usage does involve a join.

Comment: And have you reproduced that error with your simple code? I suspect not - it would be useful to have sample code which *does* reproduce the error.

Comment: @JonSkeet - edited to show something closer to my actual code.  Obviously I can't compile to see if this actually fails, but it's better than inflicting my actual code on you!

Comment: @JonSkeet, BTW did you notice I'm using the same convention for code snippets that you use in *C# in Depth*?  :-) I'm loving the book - thanks!

Comment: I hadn't, but I'm glad it's catching on. Now that you've shown the code, it makes a lot more sense - because now you've effectively got an expression tree containing a call to `Active`, which isn't the same as calling `Active` yourself (as before).

Comment: @JonSkeet, granted that it makes more sense now, but do you have a solution? :-)

Comment: Unfortunately not without rewriting expression trees :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two unrelated problems in the code. The first one is that Entity Framework cannot handle casts in expressions, which your extension method does.

The solution to this problem is to add a `class` restriction to your extension method. If you do not add that restriction, the expression is compiled to include a cast:

```
.Where (t => !((ISoftDeletable)t.IsDeleted))
```

The cast above confuses Entity Framework, so that is why you get a runtime error.

When the restriction is added, the expression becomes a simple property access:

```
 .Where (t => !(t.IsDeleted))
```

This expression can be parsed just fine with entity framework.

The second problem is that you cannot apply user-defined extension methods in query syntax, but you can use them in the Fluent syntax:

```
db.ThingContainers.SelectMany(tc => tc.Things).Active()
    .Any(t => t.SatisfiesOtherCondition); // this works
```

To see the problem we have to look at what the actual generated query will be:

```
 db.ThingContainers
       .Where(tc => tc.Things.Active().Any(t => t.StatisfiesOtherCondition))
       .Select(tc => new { ... });
```

The Active() call is never executed, but is generated as an expression for EF to parse. Sure enough, EF does not know what to do with such a function, so it bails out.

An obvious workaround (although not always possible) is to start the query at the `Thing`s instead of the `ThingContainers`:

```
db.Things.Active().SelectMany(t => t.Container);
```

Another possible workaround is to use Model Defined Functions, but that is a more involved process. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456812.aspx), [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456857.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456845.aspx) MSDN articles for more information.

Comment: It did help me on a related point, though, so +1 for that, thanks!

Comment: @Shaul, I've expanded the answer. Basically, mixing query syntax with extension methods is a pain.

Comment: Very good, but what would you do if `ThingContainer` is also `ISoftDeletable`, and I want to apply `.Active()` to that, too?  :-)

Comment: `db.Things.Active().SelectMany(t => t.Container).Active()` ;). It certainly can get to a point where you have to repeat the expression, if the query is complex enough.

Comment: Take a look at my answer for what I did in the end.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

While @felipe has earned the answer credit, I thought I would also post my own answer as an alternative, similar though it is:

```
var query = from tc in db.ThingContainers.Active() // ThingContainer is also ISoftDeletable!
            join t in db.Things.Active() on tc.ID equals t.ThingContainerID into things
            where things.Any(t => t.SatisfiesOtherCondition)
            select new { ... };
```

This has the advantage of keeping the structure of the query more or less the same, though you do lose the fluency of the implicit relationship between `ThingContainer` and `Thing`.  In my case, the trade of works out that it's better to specify the relationship explicitly rather than having to specify the `Active()` criteria explicitly.